# How to minimize the sum of absolute values

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, absolute-value

How can I solve a problem such as the following:

$$
\text{minimize}~~~ \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|
\\
\text{subject to}~~~ A x \geq b
$$
?
Without the absolute values on the variables, it is a simple linear program. Is it possible to convert the verstion with absolute values into a standard linear program?

<sub>Note: this question [How to minimize an absolute value in the objective of an LP?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/114/2576) looks similar, but it is different.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in the linked question, but with a separate variable for each summand. Explicitly, minimize $\sum_i z_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
Ax&\ge b\\
z_i&\ge x_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
z_i&\ge -x_i &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}