# How to show that minimizing the epsilon-insensitive loss is equivalent to a quadratic program with inequality constraints?

Tags: optimization, linearization, quadratic-programming, machine-learning, regression

This question is about an optimization problem that arises in [support vector regression (SVR)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html). Suppose you have $N$ pairs $(\vec{x}_n, y_n)$ as data and would like to find a vector of weights $\vec w \in\mathbb R^k$ and a bias $b \in \mathbb R$ such that function $\vec{w}^T \vec{x}_n + b \approx y_n \,\forall n$.

(Vapnik, 1995, sec. 5.9.2) introduces SVR as an empirical risk minimization problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\mathbf w, b}
\quad\frac12 w^T w + C
 \sum_{n=1}^N l(x_n,y_n; \mathbf w,b)\\
l(x_n,y_n; \mathbf w,b) = \max\left( 0, |y_n - (w^T x_n + b)| - \varepsilon \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

The $l(x_n,y_n; \mathbf w,b)$ function is known as the $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss function.

He then claims that this problem "is equivalent to the problem of finding the pair $\mathbf w, b$ that minimizes the quantity defined by slack variables $(\xi_n,\xi_n^*)_{n=1}^N$":

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\mathbf w, \mathbf\xi, \mathbf\xi^*}
&\quad\frac12 w^T w + C
 \sum_{n=1}^N (\xi_n + \xi_n^*)\\
\text{s.t.} &\quad
\begin{cases}
y_n - (w^T x_n + b) &\le \varepsilon + \xi_n^*\\
-(y_n - (w^T x_n + b)) &\le \varepsilon + \xi_n\\
\xi_n, \xi_n^* &\ge 0
\end{cases}
\forall n\in \{1,\dots,N\}
\end{aligned}
$$

My **question** is: **how** to get from the $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss to the quadratic optimization problem above? Where do the slack variables $\xi_n,\xi_n^*$ come from?

Here's what I found:

- (Smola, 2004) cites (Vapnik, 1995) and says that the above optimization problem "corresponds to dealing with a so called $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss function", but doesn't explain how to get from the $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss to the QP.
- Slides from [this CrossValidated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/287855/328515) go from the $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss to the QP with no explanation as well.
- [These slides](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehtlin/mooc/doc/206_present.pdf) (slide 11) derive the QP from the $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss step-by-step, but they don't explicitly explain why I can just introduce these random $\xi_n$ slack variables.

  In particular, why is the minimization problem with the $\varepsilon$-insensitive loss equivalent to this?
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \min_{b,w,\xi}&\quad \frac12 w^T w + C\sum_{n=1}^N \xi_n\\
  \text{s.t.}&\quad
  \begin{aligned}
  &\left| y_n - (w^T x_n + b) \right| - \varepsilon \le \xi_n\\
  &\xi_n \ge 0
  \end{aligned}\quad\forall n
  \end{aligned}
     $$

  Looks like they're trying to find the smallest $\xi_n$ such that $\max\left( 0, \left| y_n - (w^T x_n + b) \right| - \varepsilon \right) \le\xi_n$, but why is this equivalent to the original problem? How did they think of such a transformation? In what cases can it be applied?

## References

- Vapnik, V.N. (1995) ‘Chapter 5. Constructing learning algorithms’, in The Nature of Statistical Learning Theory. New York, NY: Springer New York, pp. 119–156. Available at: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3264-1. [PDF from someone's GitHub](https://github.com/muditbac/Reading/blob/master/programming/A.I/(%20)%20Vladimir%20N.%20Vapnik%20%20(auth.)-The%20Nature%20of%20Statistical%20Learning%20Theory-Springer%20New%20York%20(1995).pdf).
- Smola, A.J. and Schölkopf, B. (2004) ‘A tutorial on support vector regression’, Statistics and Computing, 14(3), pp. 199–222. Available at: https://doi.org/10.1023/B:STCO.0000035301.49549.88. [PDF from author](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2004/SmoSch04.pdf).

Comment: This is a generalization of the [usual linearization of the minimization of a sum of absolute values][1].  Because $\xi^*_n$ and $\xi_n$ have the same objective coefficient and will not both be positive at optimality, you can get by with omitting $\xi^*_n$ and just using $\xi_n$ in both constraints.

  [1]: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8831/how-to-minimize-the-sum-of-absolute-values

Comment: @RobPratt, "you can get by with omitting $\xi_n^*$" - will this result in an equivalent optimization problem? All derivations I could find, including the widely used LIBSVM library ([sec. 2.4 here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf)) and [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svr), use both $\xi_n^*$ and $\xi_n$. Now I kind of see where $\xi_n$ come from in the last optimization problem, but why are the $\xi_n^*$ there? I feel like they're redundant, but they appear in all derivations anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a simpler problem where you are given a constant $k\ge 0$ and want to find $x\in \mathbb{R}$ to minimize the (convex piecewise-linear) loss function $$\max(x-k,-k-x,0)=\begin{cases} x-k &\text{if $x> k$} \\ -k-x &\text{if $x< -k$} \\ 0 &\text{if $-k \le x\le k$}\end{cases}$$
(Note that the special case $k=0$ corresponds to $|x|$.)
[image]

One way to linearize this minimax objective is to introduce a decision variable $z$ and minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
z &\ge x - k \\
z &\ge -k - x \\
z &\ge 0
\end{align}

Another way to linearize this minimax objective is to introduce two decision variables $z^+$ and $z^-$ and minimize $z^++z^-$ subject to
\begin{align}
-k \le x - z^+ + z^- &\le k \\
z^+ &\ge 0 \\
z^- &\ge 0
\end{align}
At optimality, $z^+ = \max(x-k,0)$ and $z^- = \max(-k-x,0)$, and at most one of these can be positive, so the objective value is $z^+ + z^- = \max(x-k,-k-x,0)$, as desired.