# min matrix norm with gurobi v10+

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi, gurobipy

I was trying to use Gurobi for a minimization problem like so:
$$
\min\|M-TX\|_1
$$
where all three terms are matrices. $X$ is the nonnegative decision variable(s) of compatible size. $M$ and $T$ are nonnegative. I wanted $TX$ to approximate $M$, with $X$ being as sparse as possible in an LP. I also have some other constraints on $X$.

It seems that the MVar support in Gurobi v10 doesn't yet have a norm function, and that its general norm function only supports vectors, and that its reshape support only applies to variables, not to expressions. How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: Are you open to linearization?

Comment: @RobPratt, I think so. Some of my constraints on $X$ take advantage of its matrix form, but they can be adjusted.

Comment: You want to minimize a sum of absolute values of a linear function of $X$.  See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/114/how-to-minimize-an-absolute-value-in-the-objective-of-an-lp